# Check if scene contains any nodes with name

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I'm trying to check if a SpriteKit scene contains nodes that have a name containing "wall". 
I've tried this if statement:

```
if children.contains(name?.range(of: "wall")) {

}
```

But I get this error: 
"Cannot convert value of type 'Range?' to expected argument type 'SKNode'"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can understand what you are trying to do in your attempt, but unfortunately you generally can't write Swift the same way you write English.

You should call [`contains(where:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/2905153-contains):

```
children.contains(where: { $0.name?.contains("wall") ?? false })
```

`contains(where:)` accepts a closure. It applies the closure to each item in the sequence. If any application of the closure returns true, `contains(where:)` returns true.

Comment: This only works on the first level of children. If the wall is not a direct descendant of scene, it will be missed, so keep that in mind with using this method.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `scene.childNode(withName:"//*wall*")` to search the entire tree for a node named wall,  and if it is not nil,  then you know a wall exists.

Example:

```
if let _ = scene.childNode(withName:"//*wall*"){
  //scene contains wall
}
```

Comment: With this method though, does it work with multiple nodes that have the name wall or something with wall in their name? The reason I picked the first solution, was because I am just searching the scene for any nodes that have wall in their name.

Comment: this looks for any node containing the word wall, so stonewall, dirt wall, wally

Comment: Okay, that's good. So what would be the pros/cons for each method?

Comment: his method only searches the children, not grandchildren.  This method searches all descendants

Comment: Okay thanks for that. Could you explain to me what the //** does in the string part? I'm not familiar with that.